# jquery substract from sum (mathematical operations)

Tags: jquery

i have this jquery code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
 $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    var tot=200;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        dat=$(this).val();
        tot-=parseInt(dat);
    });
    if (tot < "20") {
        alert("You dont have any money!");
        for(i = 1; document.getElementById("bifa" + i) !== null; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById("bifa" + i).checked)
            {
            } else {
                document.getElementById("bifa" + i).disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    $('#outputDiv').html("You have: " + tot + " RON")
  });
});
</script>
```

What it does, is subtract from a total sum a certain amount. You can see it working here

http://jsfiddle.net/a2mue/1/

I just added a dropdown select on every row and is enabled when the checkbox next to it is checked. You can see that after the checkbox and the select dropdown is a number, representing the amount of money that will be subtracted from total sum. I want, when i select from the dropdown a certain value `x2` or `x3` the value of the checkbox will be multiplied by 2 or 3 depending on the selection and the from the total sum to be subtracted. For example if i check column NOV WED `28/row 06-07` and select `x2`, the the output should be "You have `200 - (30x2)=140`" and if i uncheck the input box to reverse the operation.

So can you help me solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your sample, here is modifed: http://jsfiddle.net/abaLA/

```
total = 200;
function calcSum(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        var td = $(this).parent('td');
        if($(this).attr('checked')){           
            sum += td.find('select').val() * 1 * (td.html().split('</select>')[1] * 1);
            td.find('select').attr('disabled',false);
        } else {
            td.find('select').attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
    return sum;
}

function getTotal(){
    alert(total - calcSum());
}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    getTotal();
});

$('.florin select').change(function(){
    getTotal();
});
```

Comment: one more question Boris. Is it possible to take the value from the checkbox rather than the td value? because i would like to take out the td value and only leave the input and select box.

Comment: Yes, you can put cell (td) value into not standart tag, for example 'cellval', like this: <input type='checkbox' id='bifa3' cellval='30' />, and then if($(this).attr('checked')){ value = $(this).attr('cellval') * 1 ...

Comment: hmmm getting stuck with this modifying here `sum += td.find('select').val() * 1 * (td.html().split('</select>')[1] * 1);
`

Comment: td.find('select').val() get string value of current combobox, *1 - convert to number, td.html().split('</select>')[1] - extract text from td html, *1 - convert to number to. Yuo can put cell value into <span class="celltext"> tag and extract cell value: td.find('.celltext').text(), Regards,

Comment: i am a beginner with jquery and still having problems implementing what you told me but i want to learn. Thank you for your support and help! I'll give it another go